# Permitting form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to permit certain parameters in a controller, however I can't seem to find correct way to do so.

My view to upload multiple files is:

```
<%= form_for :photo, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <br>
  <%= f.file_field :photos, multiple: true %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Upload Image"%>
<% end %>
```

In my controller, the files are located in params here:

```
params['photo']['photos'][..n..]
```

But I am unsure how to permit it correctly to allow the files to be uploaded using code like the following, similar to the example shown [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads):

```
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    @photo.save!
    @photo.file_names[..n..].url 
  end

  private
    def photo_params
      # permit here
    end
```

and is there a way which the files can be more accessible, for example in:

```
params['photos']
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be :

```rb
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :photos)
end
```

Then you can access your photos via `photo_params[:photos]`.

If `photos` is actually an array you need to permit it as an array like so:

```rb
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:title, photos: [])
end
```